# Is it possible to use "get" and "set" on anonymous functions in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, setter, getter, prototypal-inheritance

I've tried it, but perhaps the syntax is wrong:

```
course.totalScore = function get():int
{
...
}
```

I get "1084: Syntax error: expecting leftparen before get."

My impression is that this keyword is meant for use in classes only, i.e. it doesn't apply to AS3's underlying prototypal nature.

NOTE The example given is within a class method, NOT in a timeline frame script, so don't quote me livedocs please.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  It doesn't really make sense for a function to have a `get`, since it is just a function.

Comment: For my purposes it is as simple as wanting to avoid the parentheses. Syntactic sugar, nothing mission critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` and `set` functions only work on a class because they are meant to supplement the properties of a class. The don't make much sense outside of that context.

Comment: Can you clarify how they don't make sense in an outside context? There is no reason I can see why a getter/setter syntax shouldn't be possible in a prototypal context. EDIT: Ah, Travis's question makes me understand yours -- yes I agree from the point of view you fellas are taking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately, get, set and properties will only work in classes...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
course.totalScore = function ():int
{
...
}
```

Comment: I know how to write an anonymous function. Thanks.